# Angular material autocomplete wrong position

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to have my autocompletion pannel just after the searchbar but there is always the files or the message "No files found between".

**HTML: **

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <form>
      <mat-form-field class="input-sm form-control">
        <input type="text" 
          [(placeholder)]="placeholder" 
          matInput
          matAutocompleteOrigin 
          [formControl]="myControl" 
          [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
          (click)="onClick()" 
          (blur)="onBlur()" 
          (keyup)="search($event)">

          <mat-autocomplete  #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" >
               {{ option }}
              </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>

      </mat-form-field>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" [formControl]="ControlCSV" (click)="onClickCSV()">CSV</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" [formControl]="ControlPictures" (click)="onClickPictures()">Pictures</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="documentSources" class="row">
  <app-documentlist [documentSources]="documentSources"></app-documentlist>
</div>
```

I can't post the screen capture so this is the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pR8x.png

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you are using Bootstrap as well. Perhaps there are some conflicting styles causing this.

Comment: I think as well but I don't know where to look for this. Where can I find the css used for mat-autocomplete ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material and Bootstrap CSS do not mix well together. Consider removing bootstrap

Comment: Is it possible to remove bootstrap only on this part because I'm really bad with design and I don"t have the time to create a full CSS ?

Comment: If you can get the bare CSS from bootstrap and delete the elements in question; It's possible. However, a rule of thumb should be Bootstrap or Material. Even if you use a library like ngBootstrap, you'd still have the CSS issues.